# How to resolve "class not found" in PHPUnit tests?

Tags: phpunit, symfony-2.8

I have just resolved some PHPUnit problems by upgrading to the last version (6.2.1) but and I'm now able to run my tests.

However I have a new error that I can't resolve:

> 1) BackBundle\Tests\Service\LdapServiceTest::testgetLdapConnect
>   Error: Class 'BackBundle\Service\LdapService' not found

There is my classTest:

```
<?php

namespace BackBundle\Tests\Service;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use BackBundle\Service\LdapService;
use PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker;

class LdapServiceTest extends TestCase {

    public function testgetLdapConnect()
    {
        $ldap = new LdapService('10.0.0.100','10.0.0.100','mike','password',389,3,false,false);
        $ldapMock = $this->getMockBuilder( 'LdapService')->setMethods(array('getldapBind'))->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $ldapMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('getLdapBind')
            ->with(array('ldap_bind', 'mike', 'password'))
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $this->assertTrue($ldap->getLdapBind());

//        $LdapService = new LdapService();
//        $LdapService.getLdapBind();
//        $ldapMock->isAuthorized('mike', 'password');
    }
}
```

And here is my phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Here is the content of the bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
if (!defined('TEST_FILES_PATH')) {
    define('TEST_FILES_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '_files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

ini_set('precision', 14);
ini_set('serialize_precision', 14);

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// TODO: Figure out why (some of) these are required (the classes should be autoloaded instead)
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'BeforeAndAfterTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'BeforeClassAndAfterClassTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'TestWithTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'BeforeClassWithOnlyDataProviderTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'DataProviderSkippedTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'DataProviderDependencyTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'DataProviderIncompleteTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'InheritedTestCase.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'NoTestCaseClass.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'NoTestCases.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'NotPublicTestCase.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'NotVoidTestCase.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'OverrideTestCase.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'RequirementsClassBeforeClassHookTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'NoArgTestCaseTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'Singleton.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'Mockable.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'CoverageNamespacedFunctionTest.php';
require_once TEST_FILES_PATH . 'NamespaceCoveredFunction.php';
```

Comment: Why your configuration looks like a phing file?

Comment: I would guess this is a permission problem. Try dropping `sudo`, or let us know why you are using that - it is very unusual to run PHPUnit with root permissions.

Comment: Even, when i try without sudo i get the same errors

Comment: @user7791590: when replying to someone, please use their handle, like `@halfer`. I did not see your reply, and have chanced upon it by accident.

Comment: Can you edit into your question either or both of (1) how you are launching PHPUnit, in particular with the switches/flags you are using, (2) your `phpunit.xml` configuration. I have a feeling you need to include your `vendor/autoload.php` in a test bootstrap, and you're not doing so.

Comment: @halfer , please how can i include my vendor/autoload.php in a test bootstrap?

Comment: What does `bootstrap="app"` run - is there a file called "app" that is run here? Normally this looks like `bootstrap="bootstrap.php"` or something, where `bootstrap.php` is a PHP file.

Comment: A bootstrap file for tests loads everything the tests need. Assuming you're using Composer and you've done the initial install, the following will usually be sufficient, assuming it is stored in the root of the project: `<?php require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`. Make sure `vendor/autoload.php` exists, of course.

Comment: @halfer 
 
i have a boostrap.php in vendor/phpunit , i will put the content in the post but when i have changed bootstrap="app" to bootstrap="bootstrap.php" i get the following error: Cannot open file "/var/www/42backoffice/bootstrap.php"

Comment: You're not answering my main points - do you have a `vendor/autoload.php`? Are you using Composer? Did you do a `composer install`? That's three questions, please answer all of them!

Comment: You need to add the `bootstrap.php` to the root of the project, as I have indicated.

Comment: `Here is the content of the bootstrap.php:` - where is this file in relation to the project root?

Comment: @halfer yes i have a vendor/autoload and i have used composer install

Comment: @user7791590 if you have the autoload.php file in the same directory as your phpunit.xml the linke should be ```bootstrap="autoload.php"```

Comment: @halfer no actually i have the autoload file in vendor/phpunit

Comment: I don't know if the file belongs there, but you should also have one inside `vendor/` as well. Consider deleting the whole vendor file and reinstalling, on Linux that is: `rm -rf vendor && composer install`. For safety, **do not do this as root**.

Comment: I've just done `ls vendor/phpunit/` and I get `php-code-coverage  php-file-iterator  php-text-template  php-timer  php-token-stream  phpunit  phpunit-mock-objects`. I think your `autoload.php` is in the wrong place. Your vendor folder (or its contents) are not committed to your repository, right?

Comment: @halfer me too when i do ls vendor/phpunit i have php-code-coverage  php-file-iterator  php-text-template  php-timer  php-token-stream  phpunit  phpunit-mock-objects and i have also an autoload in vendor/ and a bootstrap.php , but now when i run the test i don't have the warnings anymore wich is a good thing but it takes a lot of time to run the tests i don't know why

Comment: There's no way I could have any idea, I can't see your system or your screen. If this problem is fixed, but you have another problem, please ask a new question.